# Apply modification only to substring in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string of the form "award.x_initial_value.currency" and I would like to camelize everything except the leading "x_"  so that I get a result of the form: "award.x_initialValue.currency". 
My current implementation is:

```
a = "award.x_initial_value.currency".split(".")
b = a.map{|s| s.slice!("x_")}
a.map!{|s| s.camelize(:lower)}
a.zip(b).map!{|x, y| x.prepend(y.to_s)}
```

I am not very happy with it since it's neither fast nor elegant and performance is key since this will be applied to large amounts of data.
I also googled it but couldn't find anything.
Is there a faster/better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since *"performance is key"* you could skip the overhead of `ActiveSupport::Inflector` and use a regular expression to perform the "camelization" yourself:

```
a = "award.x_initial_value.currency"
a.gsub(/(?<!\bx)_(\w)/) { $1.capitalize }
#=> "award.x_initialValue.currency"
```

Comment: Though I am unable to understand, why `'x_x_x_x'.gsub(/(?<!\bx)_(\w)/) { $1.capitalize }` works :)

Comment: @mudasobwa because `\b` is part of the negative lookbehind, i.e. it doesn't match `x_` at the beginning of a word.

Comment: Ah, clear, `'_' =~ /\w/ #⇒ 0`, I did not realize `_` is a word symbol.

Comment: @Georgiana.b: is "smooth" code better than "bumpy" code?

Comment: @CarySwoveland  In the context of "working smooth and fast" which was referring to performance, "smooth" means not producing load spikes. It might not be very explicit but I couldn't find a better word.

Answer (score 2):

```
▶ "award.x_initial_value.x_currency".split('.').map do |s|
    "#{s[/\Ax_/]}#{s[/(\Ax_)?(.*)\z/, 2].camelize(:lower)}"
  end.join('.')
#⇒ "award.x_initialValue.x_currency"
```

or, with one `gsub` iteration:

```
▶ "award.x_initial_value.x_currency".gsub(/(?<=\.|\A)(x_)?(.*?)(?=\.|\z)/) do |m|
    "#{$~[1]}" << $~[2].camelize(:lower)
  end
#⇒ "award.x_initialValue.x_currency"
```

In the latter version we use global substitution:

- `$~` is a short-hand to a global, storing *the last regexp match occured*;
- `$~[1]` is the first matched entity, corresponding `(x_)?`, because of `?` it might be either matched string, or `nil`; that’s why we use string extrapolation, in case of `nil` `"#{nil}"` will result in an empty string;
- after all, we append the camelized second match to the string, discussed above;
- **NB** Instead of `$~` for the last match, one might use [`Regexp::last_match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match)

Comment: Welcome. Lookaheads and lookbehinds always come to the rescue.

Comment: I would like to use the second one but I'm having a hard time understanding what `"#{$~[1]}" << $~[2]` does. Could you please give a hint?

Comment: Very well explained. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try solmething like this:

```
'award.x_initial_value.currency'.gsub(/(\.|\A)x_/,'\1#').camelize(:lower).gsub('#','x_')

# => award.x_initialValue.currency
```

**NOTE:** for `#` char can be used any of unused char for current name/char space.

Comment: I understood that only leading `x_` should not be camelized.

Comment: @mudasobwa You are right. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: `gsub('.x_','#')` for leading, but this assumes that string cannot contain `'#'`

Comment: @Vasfed yes, is that name with `#` valid for rails namespace?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ This is a very ingenious hack but unfortunately I have no control over what characters can appear in the string so I can't take the risk. Either way, thank you.